# react native with firebase issue

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

this same code is working with react js but not working with react native and i dont understand what is the issue ? same code is working with react native expo as well but not with react native cli

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import { View, Text, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native'
import { FirebaseApp } from './src/Services/FirebaseConfig';

import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import '@firebase/firestore'



var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyD7KpH12s63Pa_ibUFv0V_NU_JIDByRJtk",
  authDomain: "hrinstallmentscli.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://hrinstallmentscli.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "hrinstallmentscli",
  storageBucket: "hrinstallmentscli.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "587843211028",
  appId: "1:587843211028:web:e6a71a1592f7aaa42d7c01",
  measurementId: "G-XQW1WDCJ8C"
};
// Initialize Firebase
var FirebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const App = () => {
const fetchBlogs = () => {
    console.log('clicked')
    FirebaseApp.firestore().collection("checking").add({
        firstName: 'check',
        lastName: 'check last'
    })
    .then(function() {
        console.log("Document successfully written!");
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
    });

  }
 return (
    <View>
      <Text>Checking!!!</Text>
      <View>
        <TextInput placeholder="first name" onChangeText={ (value) => _OnChangeFirstName(value)} />
      </View>
      <View>
        <TextInput placeholder="last name" onChangeText={(value) => _OnChangeLastName(value)} />
      </View>
      <View>
        <Button title="Submit" onPress={() => fetchBlogs()} />
      </View>
    </View>
  )


}
```

i have tried it on web and react native expo it is working every where but not working with react native cli ... the dependencies are

> "dependencies": {
>       "firebase": "^7.14.3",
>       "react": "16.11.0",
>       "react-native": "0.62.2"   }

i dont want to use react native firebase package , i feel it is out-dated and to work with that i have to downgrade react native versions etc .

Comment: Define "not working". (And I'm not sure what specific issue you're referring to that would force a react-native downgrade, https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase doesn't seem terribly out of date.)

Comment: it might be possible that i was unable to use react-native-firebase with latest react native cli version ... regarding current issue everything is fine there is no error but data is not adding in the firebase collection

Comment: and the same code is working with react js means data adding to firebase collection successfully .